# How do I make two variables containing different parts of one number display as the same number?

Tags: python, variables, integer

```
with open("player1Cards.txt","r") as h:
for row in h:
  p1= []
  p1.append(row[0])
  p1numbers= []
  p1numbers.append(row[1])
  p1number10=[]
  p1number10.append(row[2])
```

For my code I need to compare two numbers to see which is bigger. The bigger number will win and my numbers range from 1 to 10. 
The numbers are displayed as R1 or R10, R stands for red(the player name). 
p1 appends the "R" so that I can later use that.
p1numbers appends the next row in the list which is the first digit. 
(I did the same for Player2 using p2 and p2numbers etc.)
My issue is this is that 1 and 10 both appear as 1 because I can only append the first digit. 
This is why I created p1number10 is that when I compare R10 to R1 I write

```
if p1>p2:
  print("Player 1 wins!")
else:
  print("Player 2 wins!")
```

But with R10 and R1 it's the same and comparing 1 but I can't write p1numbers+p1number10 because they are both integers. I also can't append two rows to the same variable. Do you know a way around this? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare two strings starting with one character and then a number, like `"R1"`, `"R2"`, `"R10"`, etc.

I would strip the first character, convert to integer, then compare:

```py
p1 = "R1"
p2 = "R2"
print(int(p1[1:])) # 1
print(int(p2[1:])) # 2
print(int(p1[1:]) < int(p2[1:])) # True
```

The syntactical sugar I'm using here is called array indexing (and it works on strings too). It has the same syntax as `range(start, stop, step)` except fields are separated by colons instead of commas.
So, `"R1"[1:]` takes the string `"R1"` and extracts everything after the first character.

Comment: Does this work with two digit numbers like 10 and what is it printing

Comment: Thank you so much! I just had chance to apply this to my code and it completely worked out!